# UITableView textLabels

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have the:

`cell.textLabel.text` and `cell.detailTextLabel.text`

is there a 3rd text label i can use?

Aim:

to show the 2 above text labels + a text label on the right.

Is there a way of doing this without creating a custom tableViewCell?

sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there are only these two. If you want to have more you have to create a custom cell.

You can find this information also in the class reference of UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the view(s) you need directly to the UITableViewCell

```
UILabel *myLabel = /* create and configure the label */
[myCell.contentView addSubview:myLabel];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cell.accessoryview and add a text label into that i think.

Answer (score 0):

> - (UITableViewCell *) getCellContentView:(NSString *)cellIdentifier{
>     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
>     UILabel *l1;
>     UITableViewCell *cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 60) reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

```
l1=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0, 15.0, 400.0, 40.0)];
l1.tag=1;
l1.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"AppleGothic" size:17];
//  l1.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
l1.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
l1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
l1.lineBreakMode =UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
l1.numberOfLines=3;
[cell.contentView addSubview:l1];
[l1 release];

l1=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110.0, 35.0, 650.0, 45.0)];
l1.tag =2;
l1.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura-MediumItalic" size:13];
l1.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
l1.numberOfLines=3;
l1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
l1.lineBreakMode =UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
[cell.contentView addSubview:l1];
[l1 release];




return cell;
```

}

and then call cellforrowatindexpath method 
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

```
    cell=[self getCellContentView:CellIdentifier];
```